# Splitting columns in r by combination of period and comma

Tags: r, split, multiple-columns, tidyr

I'm trying to split a column of a dataframe that has names listed into two columns. I want to separate by the existence of a period and comma combined. I'm using the tidyr library separate function. The entries in the column look something like this Lynn, M., Smith, Kris

Comment: Try this: `strsplit(x=c('Lynn, M., Smith, Kris'),split = '.,',fixed = T)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `separate` with `sep`.  By default, it uses the regex mode and `.` is a metacharacter that can match any character unless escaped (`\\`) or specify with `fixed` or wrap it inside a square (`[]`) bracket

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, names, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep="\\.,")
#    col1         col2
#1 Lynn, M  Smith, Kris
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(names = "Lynn, M., Smith, Kris")
```